# BigQuery Line numbering

Tags: google-bigquery

Maybe i'm  missing something, but does anyone know how the debugging line numbering works in BigQuery? 
I get an error like this:

`Failed to save view. 2.196 - 2.226: Ambiguous column name eventcode.`

and I'm not sure what the address 2.196-2.226 means. Specifically, what does the decimal signify? The second line of my query is very short (just `SELECT *`), so I don't think the numbers after the decimal indicate a character range?

Anyway -- I can't find any info for it in the docs, so any help here would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line counting is most like shifted by 1 so it is actually line number #1 (not #2)
196 - 226 points to char range on that line with piece of code that introduces ambiquity - just the second piece (that has already existing aliac or column name for it)

Somehow for some first lines line numbering is incremented by 1 - it can be a bug on BQ UI side.
Btw, I noticed same strange behaviour in CodeMirror BQ UI is using, so it can be CodeMirror's bug too

Comment: Thanks for the response, but even if it is identifying a char range on line 1, there are only like 30 characters in line #1 -- in fact no line has more than 80 characters, so I'm still confused by this. I'm marking this as the best answer because it at least reaffirms my suspicion that the line numbering is ambiguous/poorly-understood/broken. Thanks

Comment: agree. this is still would be great to get answer on this from google team

Comment: Are any of the tables referenced views? Views expand out into a single large query, and if the problem is in the expanded query then that may contribute to the confusion here.